# OPENSHIFT editing LD_LIBRARY_PATH & PATH for environment setting

Tags: java, linux, openshift, gurobi

I am currently working on trying to deploy my java web application onto Openshift. My web application imports Gurobi library which requires a Gurobi License Environment to run my Linear Programming model. As such i've been going around trying everything i can to get the license installed to the openshift linux server etc

I've managed to get a few things going.

1. I've SSH into my application and registered the HostName of the openshift linux platform to the license.
2. I've managed to change the `.bash_profile` file which sets up the custom environments. below are the input i have placed into the file.

   ```
   export GUROBI_HOME="/var/lib/openshift/54d4e281e0b8cd3a1400015c/jbossews/gurobi600/linux64"
   export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"
   export GRB_LICENSE_FILE="/var/lib/openshift/54d4e281e0b8cd3a1400015c/jbossews/gurobi.lic"
   ```

The problem with the input above is that I believe for `PATH` & `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, openshift automatically reinstates them everytime I access my app through the shell.

I think this has resulted in my application being unable to instanciate a `GRBENV` object which is a Gurobi Environment object which checks the `gurobi.lic` file and use the `LD_LIBRARY_FILE`.

Has anyone did something similar to this before? Really need help in this.

Brandon

Comment: Most of the time, `.bashrc` is the file you want to edit, not `.bash_profile`. You could give that a try. If it doesn't help, is there a way to find out more about the problem? (error messages, stack traces, log files...)

Comment: https://forums.openshift.com/having-my-own-rc-run-command-file-executed-on-shell-login i read up on this page of the forum for openshift, as they do not allow the developers to edit the .bashrc file we have to use the .bash_profile file instead @geert3

Comment: I´ve found a "closed bug" [https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=888377] at redhat.  I do have the same annoying problem. I just reset my path everytime I log in using ssh

Answer (score 0):

The way openshift instantiates your app and the ssh shell seems to be different. The correct place to set the environment variables are one of the start action_hooks. For instance, if you edit the .openshift/action_hooks/start file and add:

export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"

this will work for the instance that runs your APP, but not for the SSH Shell. I did the following test:
echo $PATH > $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/PATH

to confirm that the path running the APP can be set by the start hook.

I´m not sure if this solves your question (because you mention SSH shell, and I still don´t know how to set the PATH for that).